# Запятая перед "почему"

Tags: пунктуация

Вроде бы запятая нужна перед *почему*, но почему-то не хочется ее ставить. Помогите разобраться. Фраза такая:

**Запятая не нужна. Чтобы понять почему, советую прочитать ответ Арины.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Чтобы понять почему, советую прочитать ответ Арины.*

У Розенталя разбирается эта тема; там сказано, что обычно запятая не ставится, если придаточное состоит из одного союзного слова.

Она может ставится как исключение: «Что же надо делать? Науч**и**те, чт**о**».  Здесь запятая соответствует паузе, ударение падает на оба слова.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Приведённая вами фраза состоит из двух предложений, паузу перед *почему* никак не сделаешь. Поэтому запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы, не нужна.Не ставится запятая между главным и следующим за ним придаточным предложением, если придаточное состоит из одного только союзного слова(относительного местоимения или наречия). Неполное предложение замещает место члена предложения, и запятые ставятся, как в простом.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку здесь имеет место вырождение придаточного предложения в одно слово "почему" (такая аргументация приводилась по какому-то поводу Розенталем). Если же добавить к этому слову ещё одно, то можно будет трактовать пару слов как *неполное придаточное* предложение, и запятая понадобится:

> Чтобы понять, почему не нужна, советую прочитать ответ Арины.